# Could not find config for 'static files' in settings.STORAGES

Tags: django, static, django-staticfiles, python-django-storages

This error occurs when running Django 4.2.The Default: `django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage` has been deprecated.

Answer (score 11):

The Default: `django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage` has been deprecated in later versions of Django.

> Deprecated since version 4.2:
> This setting is deprecated. Starting with Django 4.2, static files storage engine can be configured with the STORAGES setting under the staticfiles key.

FIX
`STORAGES`

New in Django 4.2. 
Default:

```
STORAGES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage",
    },
    "staticfiles": {
        "BACKEND": "django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage",
    },
}`
```